# How to display previous value of a given value from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can we display the previous value of given value while the value is given from an array and we should display the previous value of it?

```
var theArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15];
const findValue = (arr, input) => {
  // To do
}
findValue(theArray, 15)
```

When we give 15 in input then the output would be 14.

Comment: what if you look for the previous from `1`? please add your code, you tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz i'm stuck to create logic for this problem

Comment: find index of wanted value, decrement index, check it and get value from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the index of the input, and then get the previous index:

```
var theArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,14,15];
const findValue = (arr, input) => arr[arr.indexOf(input) - 1]
console.log(findValue(theArray , 15))
```

You should consider the case where input is at the index 0...

Answer (score 1):

```js
const findValue = (arr, input) => {
  let previousItemIndex = arr.findIndex(e => e === input) - 1;
  return previousItemIndex < 0 ? null : arr[previousItemIndex];
}
```

This will return null if there isn't any previous item and will find from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

If it is assumed that the given value is unique, you can just search the array for the value you are looking for (probably using a known search algorithm e.g., binary search) and then return the previous index (if it is not the first item of course).